# Infinite scroll in Next.js doubles the last element on first fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch-api, strapi

I have a project that is based on Next.js fetching from Strapi Rest API. I'm fetching and rendering cards based on the content on the fetch. Since I don't want to load everything at once I implemented an infinite scroll using [react-infinite-scroller](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroller) . It works fine, my only problem is that based on the amount of elements, sometimes, the last object gets returnedagain instead of the first of the next page. This only happens on the first fetch call of the infinite loader when the user reaches the bottom of the page for the first time.

initial fetch :

```
export async function getServerSideProps({locale}, ctx) {
    const jwt = parseCookies(ctx).jwt

    if (jwt) {
        const articlesArray = await getArticles({locale}, jwt, 0, 10)
        const articles = articlesArray.articlesList
        const total = articlesArray.total
        const cookieJwt = jwt
        return {

            props: {
                articles,
                cookieJwt,
                total


            },
        }
    }

    // I DELETED THE AUTH LOGIC HERE
```

GetArticles function :

```
import qs from 'qs'

export async function getArticles({locale}, jwt,page, size) {
    const query = qs.stringify({
            pagination: {
                start: page,
                limit: size,
            },

            sort: ['date:desc'],
        },

        {
            encodeValuesOnly: true,
        });
    const fetchArticles = await fetch(`${process.env.DB_HOST}/api/articles?locale=${locale}&populate=*&${query}`,
        {
            headers: {

                Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`
            }
        })
    const articles = await fetchArticles.json()
    const articlesArray = {
        articlesList: articles.data ,
        total: articles.meta.pagination.total
    }


    return articlesArray
}
```

Infinite scroll component :

```
  <InfiniteScroll
                    pageStart={0}
                    loadMore={getMorePost}
                    hasMore={hasMore}
                    loader={<div className={cardStyle.loaderWrapper}><div className={cardStyle.loader}><Loader color={'orange'} variant={'bars'} /></div></div>}

                >
                    <SimpleGrid cols={3}
                                spacing={"xl"}
                                breakpoints={[
                                    { maxWidth: 1200, cols: 2, spacing: 'md' },
                                    { maxWidth: 755, cols: 1, spacing: 'sm' },
                                ]}>

                        {posts.map((article) => {
                                return(
                                    <ArticleCard key={newKey()} data={article} locale={locale} onClick={() => handleClick(article)} />
                                )
                            }

                        )}

                    </SimpleGrid>
                </InfiniteScroll>
```

GetMorePosts function :

```
   const getMorePost = async () => {
 
        if(pageCounter < total){


            const res = await getArticles({locale},cookieJwt, pageCounter  , 10)
            setPageCounter(pageCounter + 10)


            const newPosts = res.articlesList;
            setPosts((post) => [...post, ...newPosts]);
        }
        else {
            setHasMore(false)



        }

    };
```

As far as I can tell the first 10 elements should be loaded and the getMorePost should load the 10 next ones. However that's not exactly what happens

[the behavior can be observed here](https://chris-rime-frontend.vercel.app/press)

The full page can be found on the [repo](https://github.com/Altho/chris-rime-frontend/blob/main/pages/press.js)

Answer (score 1):

I think a quick fix to this issue could be using something like lodash's `_.uniqBy()` method (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy). That will give you a total of 19 to display on the first reload, but it would at least ensure that you don't have any duplicate items.

I think the real fix is to figure out why the API is returning that 10th item twice; it seems like the starting value might be incorrect when trying to grab from the database for the original query.

Using burp suite and playing with the proxy interceptor, it looks like the query ends up looking something like this: `/api/articles?locale=en&populate=*&pagination[start]=10&pagination[limit]=10&sort[0]=date%3Adesc`. I think if you bump up the pagination[start] by 1, that should actually fix your problem. It did for me at least.

Comment: If I bump the pagination[start] by 1 then I don't get the duplicate but I'm missing one card.

Comment: huh, weird... I was able to get the correct card when I was using burp suite to intercept the request. I would say that it might require a bit more investigation though - I'm not entirely familiar with Strapi (which is what it looks like you're using for your server), so I'm not absolutely positive how to resolve it. It does appear to either be an API issue or a request issue though. The simple fix could still be ensuring that each value is unique though.